# Laravel + datatable+ progress bar real time

Tags: laravel, datatable, datatables, laravel-5.5

i use datatable net and yajra/laravel-datatables 
I need to organize the work in this way. The "load" button sends a request for calc all the data. The calculation should be done without waiting for the result of the execution of the request for calculation from the page. And the state of the calculation must be displayed in real time in the progress bar.
In case the “load” button is pressed, the current calculations should stop and restart.
If the page has been closed, the calculations should be stopped.
I assumed that this can be done using "JOBS" + "laravel echo". But how in the “JOBS” to follow that the page has been closed or the button has been pressed. And I don’t know how to do it more correctly.

my code now

```
 table = $('#table').DataTable({
                        processing: true,
                        searching: true,
                        iDisplayLength: 50,
                        bStateSave: true,
                        order: [[0, "asc"]],
                        dom:
                        "<'row'<'col-sm-4'l><'col-sm-2'B><'col-sm-6'f>>" +
                        "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
                        "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
                        renderer: 'bootstrap',

                        ajax: {
                            url: "{{ route('data.tables.get.data') }}",
                            type: 'POST',
                            "headers": {
                                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                            },
                            "data": function (d) {
                                d.start_date = moment.unix(start_date_pic).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
                                d.end_date = moment.unix(end_date_pic).format("YYYY-MM-DD");

                            }
                        },
                        autoFill: true,
                        columns: [
                            {data: 'id', name: 'id', orderable: true,searchable: false},                       
                            {data: 'name', name: 'name', orderable: true,searchable: false},

                        }

                    });
```

Comment: Create a type of flag in another table which shares a common ID with the job? The job can "poll" the table in specific parts and check if it should cancel or not (user has left page, pressed the button again, and so on).

Comment: @Araw and how do I know that the user has left the page?